# Submit form with a drop-down list

Tags: php, html, mysql

I got an HTML-form with a drop-down list of products. When you select a product, you will have a new input field appear. For each product type input fields are different. For example: a book will have a new input field of weight, DVD will have a new input field of size and furniture will have inputs of HxWxL dimensions.
So here is the question: how is it better to submit a form to MySQL with different product types so that they are saved in one table? Without the use of if-else and switch statements.
P.S. I am sorry if this question might be asked before here.
P.S.S. And yes, code/name and price inputs are by default with each new product type.

Here is my database related code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'things') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $code= $_POST['code'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO products (code, name, price) VALUES('$code', '$name', '$price')") or die($mysqli->error);
```

And here is my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Add</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Add</h1>
        <hr>
        <?php require_once 'connect.php'; ?>
        <div class="container">
            <!--FORM-->
            <form id="form" action="connect.php" method="POST">
                <!--CODE-->
                <div id="form-group">
                    <label for="code" id="code-label"> Code</label>
                    <input type="text" id="code" name="code" required>
                </div>
                <!--NAME-->
                <div id="form-group">
                    <label for="name" id="name-label"> Name </label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
                </div>
                <!--PRICE-->
                <div id="form-group">
                    <label for="price" id="price-label"> Price </label>
                    <input type="number" id="price" name="price" required>
                </div>
                <div id="form-group">
                    <label for="product-type" id="product-type-label"> Type Switcher </label>
                    <select name="product-type" id="product-type" onchange="showHide()">
                        <option selected hidden value="">Type Switcher</option>
                        <option value="dvd">DVD</option>
                        <option value="furniture">Furniture</option>
                        <option value="book">Book</option>
                    </select>
                </div>-->
                <!--HIDDEN INPUTS-->
                <div id="size" style="display: none">
                    <div id="form-group">
                        <label for="size" id="size-label"> Size </label>
                        <input type="number" name="size" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="height" style="display: none">
                    <div id="form-group">
                        <label for="height" id="height-label"> Height </label>
                        <input type="number" name="height" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="width" style="display: none">
                    <div id="form-group">
                        <label for="width" id="width-label"> Width </label>
                        <input type="number" name="width" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="length" style="display: none">
                    <div id="form-group">
                        <label for="length" id="length-label"> Length </label>
                        <input type="number" name="length" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="weight" style="display: none">
                    <div id="form-group">
                        <label for="weight" id="weight-label"> Weight </label>
                        <input type="number" name="weight" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="save">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: _How is it better..._ - not sure what you are asking there. Also, your product table should probably be separate from some kind of attributes table if you want to be able to filter searches by those attributes. Also, your SQL in open and vulnerable to attack. You should seriously learn about prepared statements: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).